# References to NuGet packages that are missing. Package Restore or re-installing packages does not work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

In a Visual Studio solution, there are several projects, which should have the MSTest.TestAdapter NuGet package, among others. Upon downloading it from source control, each project in the solution shows an error:
"This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them."

I have tried using NuGet Package Manager to uninstall and reinstall the affected package, to no avail. I have also tried "package restore".

Each project in the solution contains a `packages.config` file, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.7.7" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Using Visual Studio 2017.

How to fix this?

Comment: You must be getting some error in the output window when you restore the package. Can you post that error here?

Answer (score -1):

Enter the `csproj` file and then delete these two lines:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('xxx\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'xx\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('xx\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'xx\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.1.2\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets'))" />
```

The two lines are still based on your source control rather than your new VS Environment. You should remove the old wrong path and then install the new path based on your current VS Environment.

**After that**, enter **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console** and then type this to reinstall all the nuget packages:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

Comment: There is a .csproj file for only one of the several projects in the solution. I edited that particular file, and the error related to that project has been resolved. How to deal with the remaining projects in the solution?

Comment: When you open the solution on VS IDE, right-click on each project->`Unload Project`--> and then right-click on the file-->`edit xxx.csproj` to remove the two xml lines. You have to do like this for each project.

Comment: That modify the csproj is the step you should do for each project. And when you finish it, you can run `update-package -reinstall` once and it works for all projects  under the solution.

Comment: @Al2110, any update about this issue?  Please let us know any feedback about this issue. If it helps, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please let us any your other concern. And we are willing to help you further.

Comment: I will try this and provide an update shortly.

Comment: And we will wait for you and provide any support if you need.